# sorting, average and finding the lowest number from a static array Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, average

i'm trying to input students and input their results for course work and exams and what i'm having trouble with is finding the average total score, the lowest total score and printing all students in order of total scores highest - lowest

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Results
{
static String[] name = new String[100];
static int[] coursework = new int[100];
static int[] exam = new int[100];
static int[] totalScore = new int[100];
static String[] totalGrade = new String[100];
static String[]examGrade = new String[100];
static int count = 0;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag = true;

    while(flag)
    {
        System.out.println(
            "1. Add Student\n" +
            "2. List All Students\n" +
            "3. List Student Grades\n" +
            "4. Total Score Average\n" +
            "5. Highest Total Score\n" +
            "6. Lowest Total Score\n" +
            "7. List all Students and Total Scores\n" +               
            "8. Quit\n");
        System.out.print("Enter choice (1 - 8): ");
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                add();
                break;
            case 2:
                listAll();
                break;
            case 3:
                listGrades();
                break;
            case 4:
                average();
                break;
            case 5:
                highestTotal();
                break;
            case 6:
                lowestTotal();
                break;
            case 7:
                order();
                break;     
            case 8:
                flag = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\nNot an option\n");

        }
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nHave a nice day");
}//end of main

static void add()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert Name: ");
    String names = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Insert Coursework: ");
    int courseworks = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Insert Exam: ");
    int exams  = input.nextInt();
    int totalscores = exams + courseworks;

    name[count] = names;
    coursework[count] = courseworks;
    exam[count] = exams;
    totalScore[count] = totalscores;

    count++;

}

static void listAll()
{
  for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
    System.out.printf("%s %d %d\n", name[i], coursework[i], exam[i]);
  }
}

static void listGrades()
{
  for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
  if(coursework[i] + exam[i] > 79)
  {
    System.out.println(name[i] + " HD");
  }
  else if(coursework[i] + exam[i] > 69)
  {
   System.out.println(name[i] + " DI"); 
  }
  else if(coursework[i] + exam[i] > 59)
  {
   System.out.println(name[i] + " CR"); 
  }
  else if(coursework[i] + exam[i] > 49)
  {
   System.out.println(name[i] + " PA"); 
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println(name[i] + " NN"); 
  }
  }
}

static void average()
{
  double sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
{
    sum += exam[i] + coursework[i];
}
sum = sum / count;
System.out.printf("Average Total Score : %.1f\n ", sum);

   }


static void highestTotal()
{
  int largest = totalScore[0];
String student = name[0];
for (int i = 0; i < exam.length; i++) {
    if (totalScore[i] > largest) {
        largest = totalScore[i];
        student = name[i];
    }
}
System.out.printf(student + ": " + largest + "\n");

}

static void lowestTotal()
{
int lowest = totalScore[0];
String student = name[0];
for (int i = 0; i > exam.length; i++) {
    if (totalScore[i] < lowest) {
        lowest = totalScore[i];
        student = name[i];
    }
}
System.out.printf(student + ": " + lowest + "\n"); 
} 



static void order()
{
  for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
  {
 Arrays.sort(totalScore);
 System.out.printf(name[i] + "\t" + totalScore[count] + "\n");
  }

  }

}
```

Comment: What's the trouble? Trouble because you're lazy? Trouble to understand what's average/lowest/sorting?

Comment: Start trying to do first and when you meet an obstacle or coding issues / bugs / problems then come back and ask instead of expecting someone else to complete your homework for you.

Comment: i updated the code code above I'm still stuck on the last 2 I just dont understand where to go from here I'm quite new to java

Answer (score 2):

```
static void average(){
 int total = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     {
         total += array[i];
     }
    int average = total / array.length
}
```

Above code you can get the Average. You did the kind of similar thing to find largest value. 
to sort array just use that will solve your problem.

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

For sorting, you can use Arrays.sort(array) (With a comparator if you need special ordering)
Once it's sorted, getting the lowest score should be easy. To get an average, add up each value and divide by the number of elements. To add them all up, use a for loop or for-each loop:

```
 int sum = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     {
         sum += array[i];
     }
    int average = sum / array.length
```

You may want to use a double instead of an int for sum.

Answer (score 0):

For **Average Total Score** simply add the coursework and exam scores in avariable such as sum and divide by no. of students:

```
static void average() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        sum += exam[i] + coursework[i];
    }
    sum = sum / count;
    System.out.printf("Average Total Score  =  : " + sum + "\n");
}
```

For both **lowest total score** and **largest total score** your implementation of highest total is almost right. The problem is that you are not considering the **coursework[i]** in your **largest** variable. And on similar lines you can implement **lowest total score**

```
static void highestTotal() {
    int largest = exam[0] + coursework[0];
    String student = name[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < exam.length; i++) {
        if (exam[i]+coursework[i] > largest) {
            largest = exam[i] + coursework[i];
            student = name[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.printf(student + ": " + largest + "\n");
}
```

For printing the scores in order i would suggest that you define another int array which has the sum of exam score and coursework score, sort it using any basic sorting technique and print the array. Remember while exchanging the **sum** during sorting also exchange the corresponding **name**..

Comment: I still cant get the lowest total score

   
`static void lowestTotal(){`
  `int lowest = exam[0] + coursework[0];`
    `String student = name[0];
    for (int i = 100; i > exam.length; i--) {
        if (exam[i]+coursework[i] < lowest) {
            lowest = exam[i] + coursework[i];
            student = name[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.printf(student + ": " + lowest + "\n");
`

Comment: Check your for loop, it is wrong.......

Comment: i keep changing it but i cant get it to work

Comment: the no. of students in your list is **exam.length** or **count** but you are iterating over the loop **100 - count** times. just correct that and you are good to go...